# Extracting group only if previous group was matched

Tags: regex

I have two examples

```
abc 34 def12 ghi
abc 34 33 ghi
```

and a regexp

```
^.*?([0-9]{2}) ?([a-z]{2,3})? ?([0-9]{2}).*$
```

(see https://regex101.com/r/U2JNaS/1)

I need to modify it in such way to extract `$1`, `$2`, `$3` but **only if** `$2` was present, i.e. I need it to return

```
34 def12
<WRONG>
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: @anubhava sorry, I made it not clear: substitute function gives me everything if there is no match, I meant that the second example does not match (edited).

Comment: Then make 2nd non-optional as: [`^.*?([0-9]{2})\s*([a-z]{2,3})\s*([0-9]{2}).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/U2JNaS/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you put a `?` after the second capturing group (`([a-z]{2,3})`).

It causes that the whole regex will match even if the particular row does not contain the "letter" part.

Just remove this `?`, so that in this case the whole regex will not match.